# Using uniform() in Wicket generates multiple instances when invoking the modelChanged method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wicket-6

I am trying to implement a simple dropdown which is updated based on the selection of another dropdown with Wicket 6.19. So far so good, the dropdown work as they should. The problem is that I am using a customized dropdown choice component where in the renderHead methode the uniform() methode is called.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    super.renderHead(response);
    response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#" + getMarkupId(true) + "').uniform();"));
}
```

This methode (it was written by someone else) is always called when I invoke the modelChanged() methode of my dropdown to be updated. Thus, a new div element is created everytime this renderHead method is called which results on the screen in a shadow aound the component.

[Generated HTML after changing the selection of the dropdown several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdQr5.png)

When I remove the code with the uniform, the addional divs are not generated but the drop down has the wrong style. I am not familiar with the uniform methode. I would really appreciate your help how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know quite some time passed since my question but recently I came by a solution. I know this is probably not the best solution but it works for me and maybe it helps someone who stumbles over the same problem.

In this solution I remove the div and child span element before performing uniform again. This way, I have only one div after I invoke the uniform method.

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        if(hasBeenRendered())
            response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#" + getMarkupId(true) + "').parent().replaceWith(function() {return $('select', this);});"));

        response.render(OnDomReadyHeaderItem.forScript("$('#" + getMarkupId(true) + "').uniform();"));      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the code in `renderHead()` with `if (!hasBeenRendered()) {...}`. This way it will `uniform` it only the first time.

Comment: I have tried it but in that case, after I changed the selection of my first dropdown, the custom style of the dropdown it not applied anymore.

Comment: What I am doing on a specific change is that I clear the list with items of the second drop down and set the item of the selection model to null. On another change I fill the list again and set the selection model.

Comment: You either need a `deuniform()` method that `destroy`s the JS widget if it is there or you need to remove all the DOM completely and add a new DropDownChoice that will be `uniform`-ed because it hasn't been rendered before.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try it as soon as I have time and let you know if it worked.